# My visa in Germany expired and want to tour around Europe for a month

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, tourist-visas

I've been in Germany for almost three months doing an internship and just realized my visa expired even though my working contract is still going.

I went to the Ausländerbehörde  and they told me that since I'm illegal right now I have to leave the country and they are going to give a paper so I can leave without legal problems.

The problem is that my flight back is at the end of next week from Spain, I want to know if it is possible to go out with this document and reenter as a tourist without problems (for my country it's not required a tourist visa). I don't want to lose this trip opportunity to but I don't want to get my access denied.

Comment: if the paper given to you extends your permit for 3 months is based on § 7 Absatz 1 Satz 3, then that allows you to use the 90/180 rule **without** leaving the Schengen Area. Source: **Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift
zum Aufenthaltsgesetz** 6.1.8.2.